# How to move multiple files at once from local-server to HDFS inside python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, subprocess, hdfs

I am using python v3.4 on my server and I frequently need to copy/move multiple files from my local directory to hdfs directory. All my files are in sub-directories, which in turn are in MyDir. Here is the command which I use-

`$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal MyDir/* /path/to/hdfs/`

This command runs fine on server, but when I use the same command inside python using subprocess

`>>> subprocess.call(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyFromLocal', 'MyDir/*', '/path/to/hdfs/'])`

It gives the following error-

```
copyFromLocal: `MyDir/*': No such file or directory
1
```

P.S.- I also tried `['hadoop', 'fs', '-put'....]` instead of `['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyFromLocal'....]`, it is also not working.

Can anyone help me on this? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT- I need to move files along with sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

add `shell=True`:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyFromLocal', 'MyDir/*', '/path/to/hdfs/'], shell=True)
```

Read this post: [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/3131945)

Comment: I tried it, it returned `hadoop command usage` alongwith `zero exit status`, but when I checked the files in hdfs path, they are not there.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function with subprocess that gives you output and error:

```
import subprocess
def run_cmd(args_list):
    """
    run linux commands
    """
    # import subprocess
    print('Running system command: {0}'.format(' '.join(args_list)))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
    s_return =  proc.returncode
    return s_return, s_output, s_err
```

Then:

```
 import os
 for file in os.listdir('your-directory'):
     run_cmd(['hadoop', 'fs', '-put', 'your-directory/{0}'.format(file), 'target-directory'])
```

That should loop through all of the files in your directory and put them in your desired HDFS directory

Answer (score 1):

Append everything in the command into a single string and give parameter **shell = True**

```
subprocess.call('hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal MyDir/* /path/to/hdfs/', shell = True)
```